# How to recursively reverse a Linked list with double pointers

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

The goal is to reverse a series integers 1 2 3 4 5 into 5 4 3 2 1.

This is the structure definition:

```
typedef struct _listnode
{
    int item;
    struct _listnode *next;
} ListNode;         // You should not change the definition of ListNode

typedef struct _linkedlist
{
    int size;
    ListNode *head;
} LinkedList;
```

I have a function that is called using this
`RecursiveReverse(&(ll.head));`

```
void RecursiveReverse(ListNode **ptrHead)
{
    ListNode *curr,*q;
    curr = *ptrHead; //same as ll.head

    if(curr == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }

    if(curr->next == NULL)
    {
        *ptrHead = curr;
        return;
    }
    RecursiveReverse(&(curr->next));
    q = curr->next;
    q->next = curr;
    curr->next = NULL;
}
```

At this step, if my input is 1 2 3 , the output is only 1. 
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please create a [mre] with suitable sample data and output to demonstrate your problem,

Comment: `ptrHead = curr;` has no effect. Did you mean `*ptrHead = curr;`?

Comment: @user58697 i tried that but nothing different happens

Comment: You also have to update where the `->next` node is pointing. If you fail to do that, you will simply have your original list when you are done. What you are doing in the reversal is called *forward-chaining*. That may provide a useful search term.

Comment: `if(curr == NULL) ` never executes because you get to `if(curr->next == NULL)` first and return. [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) means something I can copy/paste and then compile to help you with your question without having to write code to get it to that point.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin i updated the code, but the output is only 1.

Comment: Give me a few minutes to think through the recursive logic. (you generally want to avoid recursion where an iterative solution will do -- but this is probably a learning exercise)

Comment: you will end up in copying all the values to an array, reason being that you are not having a pointer to the previous item in your `struct` like `head->prev` so that you can traverse backwards

Comment: there is an example here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34466255/reversing-every-k-nodes-of-a-linked-list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have your `LinkedList` as a wrapper struct around `ListNode`, you will need to provide a wrapper function that takes a `LinkedList*` argument and then calls the actual recursive function that does the work passing the `prev` and `current` nodes as arguments. This can be done as:

```
/** recursive reversal of list */
ListNode *revlist (ListNode *cur, ListNode *prev)
{
    if (cur->next != NULL) {
        ListNode *next = cur->next;
        cur->next = prev;
        return revlist (next, cur);
    }
    else {
        cur->next = prev;
        return cur;
    }
}

/** recursive reversal of list (wrapper) */
void rev (LinkedList *l)
{
    l->head = revlist (l->head, NULL);
}
```

In your code you would simply call:

```
rev (ptr_to_list);
```

**Note:** using a wrapper `LinkedList` is good it also allows you to add a `tail` pointer for O(1) insertions at the end.

A short example that builds and reverses the list would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct _listnode {
    int item;
    struct _listnode *next;
} ListNode;

typedef struct _linkedlist {
    int size;
    ListNode *head, *tail;
} LinkedList;

/** add node at end of list, update tail to end */
ListNode *add (LinkedList *l, int v)
{
    ListNode *node = malloc (sizeof *node); /* allocate node */
    if (!node) {                            /* validate allocation */
        perror ("malloc-node");
        return NULL;
    }
    node->item = v;                         /* initialize members values */
    node->next = NULL;

    if (!l->head)                   /* if 1st node, node is head/tail */
        l->head = l->tail = node;
    else {                          /* otherwise */
        l->tail->next = node;       /* add at end, update tail pointer */
        l->tail = node;
    }

    return node;    /* return new node */
}

/** print all nodes in list */
void prn (LinkedList *l)
{
    if (!l->head) {
        puts ("list-empty");
        return;
    }
    for (ListNode *n = l->head; n; n = n->next)
        printf (" %d", n->item);
    putchar ('\n');
}

/** delete all nodes in list */
void del (LinkedList *l)
{
    ListNode *n = l->head;
    while (n) {
        ListNode *victim = n;
        n = n->next;
        free (victim);
    }
}

/** recursive reversal of list */
ListNode *revlist (ListNode *cur, ListNode *prev)
{
    if (cur->next != NULL) {
        ListNode *next = cur->next;
        cur->next = prev;
        return revlist (next, cur);
    }
    else {
        cur->next = prev;
        return cur;
    }
}

/** recursive reversal of list (wrapper) */
void rev (LinkedList *l)
{
    l->head = revlist (l->head, NULL);
}

int main (void) {

    LinkedList l = { .size = 0 };

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        add (&l, i+1);

    prn (&l);
    rev (&l);
    prn (&l);
    del (&l);
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/lls_rec_rev
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to ensure you do not attempt to access memory or write beyond/outside the bounds of your allocated block, attempt to read or base a conditional jump on an uninitialized value, and finally, to confirm that you free all the memory you have allocated.

For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. There are similar memory checkers for every platform. They are all simple to use, just run your program through it.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/lls_rec_rev
==7081== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==7081== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==7081== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==7081== Command: ./bin/lls_rec_rev
==7081==
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
==7081==
==7081== HEAP SUMMARY:
==7081==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7081==   total heap usage: 11 allocs, 11 frees, 1,184 bytes allocated
==7081==
==7081== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==7081==
==7081== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==7081== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Always confirm that you have freed all memory you have allocated and that there are no memory errors.

Answer (score 0):

This code is working try it, I fixed the size to 5

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct _listnode
{
    int item;
    struct _listnode *next;
} ListNode;         // You should not change the definition of ListNode

struct _listnode* RecursiveReverse(struct _listnode* head)
{
    struct _listnode *temp = head;
    struct _listnode *curr = head;
    struct _listnode *prev = NULL;
    struct _listnode *next = NULL;
    int count = 0;

    // Reverses the first k nodes iteratively
    while (curr != NULL && count < 5){
            next = curr->next;
            curr->next = prev;
            prev = curr;
            curr = next;
            count++;
    }

    if (next != NULL) temp->next = RecursiveReverse(next);
    return prev;
}

int main() {
   struct _listnode* head = NULL; 
   struct _listnode* item2 = NULL; 
   struct _listnode* item3 = NULL; 
   struct _listnode* item4 = NULL; 
   struct _listnode* item5 = NULL; 

   struct _listnode* reverse = NULL; 

   head = (struct _listnode*)malloc(sizeof(struct _listnode));
   item2 = (struct _listnode*)malloc(sizeof(struct _listnode));
   item3 = (struct _listnode*)malloc(sizeof(struct _listnode));
   item4 = (struct _listnode*)malloc(sizeof(struct _listnode));
   item5 = (struct _listnode*)malloc(sizeof(struct _listnode));

   item5->item = 5;
   item5->next = NULL;

   item4->item = 4;
   item4->next = item5;

   item3->item = 3;
   item3->next = item4;

   item2->item = 2;
   item2->next = item3;

   head->item = 1;
   head->next = item2;

   reverse = RecursiveReverse(head);

   while (reverse != NULL) { 
      printf(" %d ", reverse->item); 
      reverse = reverse->next; 
   }

   return 0;
}
```